# Problem calling form while closing the current one

Tags: vb.net

I am having problem closing current form when I call some other form from current one.
For example when I use code

me.dispose (I tried me.close too)
frmExam.ShowDialog()

It closes the current form but does not call frmExam.vb

How to fix it?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show it and then close it!

```
frmExam.ShowDialog()
me.close()
```

Comment: But first form remains active in the backgroud, that I donot want

Comment: @user415037, then you should use me.Dispose() instead of me.Close().